# How to make routing differently than is now vuejs routing

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a problem. I made routing what according how many addresses have user it will display them in manner 'Addresses(addrescount)'. global variable for getting address count is '$auth.user.address_count'

Task was if user have addresses show their count in sidebar if user do not have addresses show nothing .I did that but is any chance to have another solution to this problem

Is any chance to make it different then it now is?
[how it looks like in programm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCEUi.png)

see line before `{{route.display}}`

```html
<template>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="profile-sidebar">
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li v-for="route in nodes" :key="route.name">
                    <router-link :to="route.fullPath">
                        <template v-if="route.display === route.meta.title && $auth.user.address_count>0">
                            {{ route.display }}({{$auth.user.address_count}})
                        </template>
                        <template v-else>
                            {{ route.display }}
                        </template>
                    </router-link>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import { routes } from '@/routes/routes';

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                nodes: [],

            }
        },
        async created() {
            if (!this.$auth.user)
                await this.$auth.updateUserInfo();
            this.loadProfileNodes();
            
        },
        methods: {
            loadProfileNodes() {
                let node = routes.filter(route => route.path === '/profile').pop();
                let hasLocalAccount = this.$auth.hasLocalAccount;
                this.nodes = [];

                node.children.forEach((route) => {
                    route['fullPath'] = node.path + '/' + route.path;

                    if ((!hasLocalAccount && route.path !== 'change-password') || (hasLocalAccount && route.path !== 'set-password')) {
                        this.nodes.push(route);
                    }
                });
            }
        },

    }
</script>
```

my **routes.js** see `/profile` children `address-list` route.

```js
const routeOptions = [
    { path: '/', name: 'default', view: 'home', display: 'Home', meta: { showInMenu: true } },
    { path: '/401-forbidden', name: 'forbidden', view: 'errors/401-forbidden', display: '401 Forbidden' },
    { path: '/404-not-found', name: 'not-found', view: 'errors/404-not-found', display: '404 Page Not Found' },
    { path: '/login', name: 'login', view: 'auth/login' },
    { path: '/register', name: 'register', view: 'auth/register' },
    { path: '/auth/forgot-password', view: 'auth/forgot-password' },
    { path: '/auth/reset-password', view: 'auth/reset-password', props: (route) => ({ code: route.query.code }) },
    { path: '/auth/confirm-email', view: 'auth/confirm-email', props: (route) => ({ userId: route.query.userId, token: route.query.token }) },
    { path: '/admin/user-list', view: 'admin/users/user-list', display: 'Users', meta: { showInMenu: true, auth: { roles: 'Admin' } } },
    { path: '/admin/company-list', view: 'admin/companies/company-list', display: 'Companies', meta: { showInMenu: true, auth: { roles: 'Admin' } } },

    {
        path: '/profile',
        view: 'profile/profile',
        display: 'Edit profile',
        meta: { auth: true },
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                display: 'My Profile',
                view: 'profile/edit-profile',
                meta: { auth: true }
            },
            {
                path: 'manage-logins',
                display: 'External Logins',
                view: 'profile/manage-logins',
                meta: { auth: true }
            },
            {
                path: 'address-list',
                display: 'Addresses',
                view: 'profile/addresses/address-list',
                meta: { auth: true, title: 'Addresses' }
            },
            {
                path: 'change-password',
                display: 'Change Password',
                view: 'profile/change-password',
                meta: { auth: true }
            },
            {
                path: 'set-password',
                display: 'Set Password',
                view: 'profile/set-password',
                meta: { auth: true }
            }
        ]
    },

    { path: '*', redirect: { name: 'not-found' } }
];

function addDynamicImport(route) {
    if (!route.view)
        return route;

    if (route.children && route.children.length) {
        route.children = route.children.map(child => {
            return addDynamicImport(child);
        });
    }

    return {
        ...route,
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "[request]" */ `@/components/views/${route.view}`)
    }
}

const routes = routeOptions.map(route => {
    return addDynamicImport(route);
})


export { routes }
```

**router.js**

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import { routes } from './routes';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

let router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes
});

export default router;
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is simple. You can add flag into '/profile/addres-list' route meta tag and check it if it is true/ True means we found the needed page

```
{
                path: 'address-list',
                display: 'Addresses',
                view: 'profile/addresses/address-list',
                meta: { auth: true, title: 'Addresses' }
            },
```

into this (difference in the last line)

```
{
                path: 'address-list',
                display: 'Addresses',
                view: 'profile/addresses/address-list',
                meta: { auth: true, isAddressList: true }
            }
```

and change

```
<template v-if="route.display === route.meta.title &&$auth.user.address_count>0">
```

to this

```
<template v-if="route.meta.isAddressList && $auth.user.address_count>0">
```